# Specifying json key mappings for AWS Firehose taking DMS data as an input

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-kinesis-firehose, aws-dms

I want to migrate some data on AWS using Kinesis, and store it in an S3 bucket after converting it to Parquet. The set up is very similar to [this one](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/stream-cdc-into-an-amazon-s3-data-lake-in-parquet-format-with-aws-dms/). The architecture looks as follows:

- My data is moved via AWS DMS to a Kinesis Data Stream .
- Then I use Kinesis Firehose to convert the data to Parquet and store it on S3.

I have previously created a Glue table crawling the DMS data. DMS adds some metadata to the original data, and the metadata field names contain the character "-". However, Kinesis Firehose does not recognise this character and fails during the data conversion from JSON into Parquet, returning the following error message: `expected at the position 30 of ‘struct’ but ‘-’ is found.`

To fix this, I need to specify JSON key mappings, which cannot be done on the AWS Management console. Here is where I struggle, since I have never used AWS CLI before.

The previously cited post contains the following snippet:

```
"S3BackupMode": "Disabled",
                    "DataFormatConversionConfiguration": {
                        "SchemaConfiguration": {
                            "RoleARN": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/sample-firehose-delivery-role",
                            "DatabaseName": "sample-db",
                            "TableName": "sample-table",
                            "Region": "us-east-1",
                            "VersionId": "LATEST"
                        },
                        "InputFormatConfiguration": {
                            "Deserializer": {
                                "OpenXJsonSerDe": {
                                "ColumnToJsonKeyMappings":
                                {
                                 "record_type": "record-type","partition_key_type": "partition-key-type","schema_name":"schema-name","table_name":"table-name","transaction_id":"transaction-id"
                                }
                                }
```

Unfortunately, this snippet is incomplete. Could you help me complete it and run it on CLI?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: You need to create the Delivery Stream from AWS CLI as follows:

```
aws firehose create-delivery-stream --cli-input-json file://my_firehose.json
```

where my_firehose.json is a file containing all the necessary configuration options. You can see what this file must look like generating a template with the following command:

```
aws firehose create-delivery-stream --generate-cli-skeleton
```

This will create the delivery stream, but the mapping does not seem to be working because all the processed records have an error:

```
"DataFormatConversion.InvalidSchema"
"The schema is invalid. Error parsing the schema: Error: : expected at the position 30 of 'struct<timestamp:string,record-type:string,operation:string,partition-key-type:string,schema-name:string,table-name:string,transaction-id:int>' but '-' is found.
```

Any ideas on how to solve the '-' issue?